# Forcing SSL on some URLs when Java app is behind load balancer

Tags: java, ssl, heroku, https, load-balancing

I have a Java web app where I have defined that some URLs must only be accessed via HTTPS - this is done using the security-constraint definition in web.xml as below:

```
<security-constraint>
                <web-resource-collection>
                        <web-resource-name>SSL URLs</web-resource-name>
                        <url-pattern>/j_spring_security_check</url-pattern>
                        <url-pattern>/secure/account/create</url-pattern>
                        <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
                        <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
                        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
                        <http-method>GET</http-method>
                <http-method>POST</http-method>
                </web-resource-collection>
                <user-data-constraint>
                        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
                </user-data-constraint>
        </security-constraint>
```

My problem is, when I deploy my application to Heroku and try to piggyback off its SSL connection, my application is behind a load balancer, and each request coming into the app is HTTP, therefore, the above definition in my web.xml forces a redirect to the SSL URL, which again comes into the app as HTTP, and so it ends up in a redirect loop which shows as an error in my browser.

I'm not really sure how to handle this, I've read that I can look at the x-forwarded-proto which should tell me whether the original request was https or http, but I don't know what to do with it as the above security-constraint will always kick in. Should I be deleting the security-constraint section and enforcing the https programmatically? It doesn't seem ideal to me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your load balancer forwards the information about the SSL then your application should be able to recognize that the connection is encrypted even if the connection to the application server itself is not.